# MySQL convert Trigger from Update to Insert

Tags: mysql

I have an AFTER UPDATE Trigger that performs an UPDATE. I’ve been trying to convert the Trigger from an AFTER UPDATE UPDATE to an AFTER UPDATE INSERT to see if the performance is better. I however cannot get it close to working.

Most of my attempts have involved trying to use INSERT INTO with a SELECT statement, but I get unknown column errors and multiple errors related to my WHERE clauses. My latest error is: “Operand should contain 1 column(s)”

Expected Outcome: When a column in Table1 is updated, then INSERT the matching rows(by id,session) from view1 into Table3. An INSERT into Table3 for id1 might look like:

```
id | session | results1 | results2 | results3
1      1          BCE      GOOG      TSLA
1      2          S&P      ARKK      TSLA
```

The current UPDATE trigger updates each column independently, I would like the whole row inserted, like the example above.

The fiddle should help it make more sense: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=56868344c95a250b47899c47471576be

Comment: Your fiddle contains trivial syntax error. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d82852e3cb55172607e2f6a8a87faa39

Comment: @Akina I’ve played around with the fiddle a bit more. It’s ignoring the session part. Any ideas as to why? I’ve tried a few versions with session in the where clause with no luck.

Comment: "ignoring the session part" isn't clear. What are you expecting from what query?

Comment: @danblack  If I update for id 1 session 2, it inserts for session 1. I want it to know which session was updated and insert with the appropriate session number.

Comment: Is that the "desired" result for the Trigger?  If not ,please explain, in the fiddle, what you expect to happen.

Comment: @RickJames , Updated the Fiddle. See my notes at the bottom. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c8e497966fded8d3e3d11e986514ff35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps instead of

```
where view1.id = NEW.id
limit 1;
```

you want

```
where view1.id = NEW.id
  AND view1.session = new.session;
```

??